# combinations which way way is correct?

Tags: combinatorics

## The problem

> How many ways are there to select 5 persons: 2 men and 2 women from a group of 20 people: 12 men and 8 women.

So far I've found 2 solutions:

1. We select 3 men and 2 women or 2 men and 3 women:
   $$\binom {12}{3} \times \binom 82 + \binom {12}{2} \times \binom 83 = 9856$$
2. We select 2 men and 2 women and one other person (man or women):
   $$\binom {12}{2} \times \binom 82 \times \binom {16}1 = 29568  $$

What is wrong about the second method? (or is it the first? :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second method overcounts by a factor of $3$.  For instance if $3$ women, Alice, Betty, Carol, end up being selected, in method $2$ did we select A, B as the original two, or A, C, or B, C?

Answer (score 1):

You can think of the second method as counting the number of ways to form a *chaired* committee with $2$ men and $2$ women in the non-chair positions.  This explains why that count is $3$ times the other:  the chair can be viewed as the leader of the majority, whether it's men or women, so in either case can be any of the three members of that group.